# Images not coming id wise

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There are 2/3 users in my database and in another table there are some pictures against each users.(Example:userA has img1,img2,img3 || UserB has imga,imgb,imgc).
when i trying to fetch data from database but with every profile image is showing but those images are from the last users .Meaning if userB is last user in database then at the time of display images everywhere the imges are showing are the images of userB.

Below are the codes:

Controller

```
public function index()
    {   
        $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
        $data['articles']  = $this->interior->interior_list();
       // $type_id   = $this->input->get('score');
        foreach ($data['articles'] as $article) {
        $type_id = $article['type_id'];
        $data['particles'] = $this->interior->image_list($type_id);
        }

        //echo($type_id);
        // Load Interior Listing View
        $this->load->view("interior/interior",$data);
    }
```

Model

```
class Interior_listing_model extends CI_model
{
    public function interior_list()
  {
    //$query = $this->db->get('interior_testing');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('interior_testing', array('category_id' => 1),0,0);
    return $query->result_array();

  }
public function image_list($type_id)
  { 

    $query = $this->db->get_where('interior_image_testing', array('type_id' => $type_id),3,0);
    return $query->result_array();

  }

}
```

view

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"/> <!-- needs to be renamed -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="tophead">
      <!--menu start-->
     <nav> 
      <div class="custom_nav">
        <div class="logoimg pull-left">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
             <img class="logo" src="assets/img/WhiteLogo.png">   
           </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_items" class="pull-right">
         <a class="mobile_toggle_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>   
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
         </ul>   
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      <!--menu end-->
      <!---writing start-->
        <div class="text-center">
          <h3>Find the right designer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="quote" href="<?php echo base_url('BluemasonsForm/registration'); ?>">Get Free Quote</a>
        </div>
      <!---writing end-->
    </div>
    <!-- The subview section starts here -->  
    <div class="container">
      <!--Category start-->
        <div class="text-center category">
           <a class="catname activecat" href= "<?php echo base_url(''); ?>" >Interior</a> 

           <a class="catname" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/architect'); ?>">Architect</a>
<!--           <a class="catname" href="#">Interior & Architect</a>-->
<!--           <a class="catname" href="#">Others</a>-->
        </div>
      <!--Category end-->  
    </div>
    <!-- type your image fetching query here -->
    <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>

    <!--###################################################################################-->
    <!---listing section start-->
    <div class="listing">
     <div class="container">
         <!---1st list start-->
       <div class="row listelements">
        <!---listing Profile strat-->
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">  
           <div class="media">
            <img class="d-flex mr-1 img-circle" src="assets/img/<?= $article['profile_pic'] ?>" alt="Profile Picture"> <!-- needs to be changed -->
              <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="mt-0"><?= $article['name'] ?></h5>
                <!--<input type="text" name="id" value="<?= $article->type_id ?>"> --> 
                  <span class="text-center"><?= $article['type'] ?></span><br/>
                     <span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp; <?= $article['location'] ?></span><br/>
                  <span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Contact</span>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div> 

        <!---listing Profile end--> 
        <!---Profile image start-->

         <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
           <div class="row mobileimage">



            <?php foreach($particles as $particle): ?>

            <?php foreach($particle as $particle_one): ?>

              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
                <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle_one['image_path'] ?> " width="100%"> 
              </div> 
            <?php endforeach; ?>  

            <?php endforeach; ?>   
            <!--- View all strat-->
            <div class="col-12">
               <a class="viewall pull-right" href="<?php echo base_url("details/profile/".$article['type_id']); ?>">
                 View all  
               </a>   
            </div>    
           <!--- View all end-->
           </div>    
         </div>

        <!---Profile image end-->
        </div>
         <!---1st list end-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <!-- Show more option-->
    <div class="col-12">
      <p class="text-center" id="load_more">
          <a> Show more 
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
          </a>
      </p>
    </div>

 <!---listing section end-->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script> <!-- needs to be renamed -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use join query . rather than using separate queries. Show your table stractures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Controller code

```
public function index()
    {   
        $articles = array();
        $this->load->model("Interior_listing_model","interior");
        $articlesArray  = $this->interior->interior_list();
        // $type_id   = $this->input->get('score');
        foreach ($articlesArray as $article) {

            $article['images'] = $this->interior->image_list($article['type_id']);
            $articles[] = $article; 
        }

        $data['articles'] = $articles;
        // Load Interior Listing View
        $this->load->view("interior/interior",$data);
    }
```

Chagne your View code like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> 
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css"/> <!-- needs to be renamed -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="tophead">
      <!--menu start-->
     <nav> 
      <div class="custom_nav">
        <div class="logoimg pull-left">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
             <img class="logo" src="assets/img/WhiteLogo.png">   
           </a>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_items" class="pull-right">
         <a class="mobile_toggle_menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>   
            <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>   
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>   
         </ul>   
        </div>
      </div>
      </nav>
      <!--menu end-->
      <!---writing start-->
        <div class="text-center">
          <h3>Find the right designer</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="quote" href="<?php echo base_url('BluemasonsForm/registration'); ?>">Get Free Quote</a>
        </div>
      <!---writing end-->
    </div>
    <!-- The subview section starts here -->  
    <div class="container">
      <!--Category start-->
        <div class="text-center category">
           <a class="catname activecat" href= "<?php echo base_url(''); ?>" >Interior</a> 

           <a class="catname" href="<?php echo base_url('welcome/architect'); ?>">Architect</a>
<!--           <a class="catname" href="#">Interior & Architect</a>-->
<!--           <a class="catname" href="#">Others</a>-->
        </div>
      <!--Category end-->  
    </div>
    <!-- type your image fetching query here -->
    <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>

    <!--###################################################################################-->
    <!---listing section start-->
    <div class="listing">
     <div class="container">
         <!---1st list start-->
       <div class="row listelements">
        <!---listing Profile strat-->
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">  
           <div class="media">
            <img class="d-flex mr-1 img-circle" src="assets/img/<?= $article['profile_pic'] ?>" alt="Profile Picture"> <!-- needs to be changed -->
              <div class="media-body">
                <h5 class="mt-0"><?= $article['name'] ?></h5>
                <!--<input type="text" name="id" value="<?= $article->type_id ?>"> --> 
                  <span class="text-center"><?= $article['type'] ?></span><br/>
                     <span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>&nbsp; <?= $article['location'] ?></span><br/>
                  <span class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp; Contact</span>
              </div>
            </div>
         </div> 

        <!---listing Profile end--> 
        <!---Profile image start-->

         <div class="col-lg-9 col-12">
           <div class="row mobileimage">



            <?php foreach($article['images'] as $particle): ?>



              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
                <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle['image_path'] ?> " width="100%"> 
              </div> 

            <?php endforeach; ?>   
            <!--- View all strat-->
            <div class="col-12">
               <a class="viewall pull-right" href="<?php echo base_url("details/profile/".$article['type_id']); ?>">
                 View all  
               </a>   
            </div>    
           <!--- View all end-->
           </div>    
         </div>

        <!---Profile image end-->
        </div>
         <!---1st list end-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    <!-- Show more option-->
    <div class="col-12">
      <p class="text-center" id="load_more">
          <a> Show more 
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
          </a>
      </p>
    </div>

 <!---listing section end-->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script> <!-- needs to be renamed -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. Once again, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your array variable is overwriting each and every time. change your loop in controller as below:

```
foreach ($data['articles'] as $article) {
        $type_id = $article['type_id'];
        $data['particles'][] = $this->interior->image_list($type_id); // append each value to array
        }
```

Also if there are multiple images related to each user you also have to loop twice in view

```
 <?php foreach($particles as $particle): ?>

      <?php foreach($particle as $particle_one): ?>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-6 workimg">
            <img src="assets/img/<?= $particle_one['image_path'] ?> " width="100%"> 
          </div> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>  

 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I am getting the same images repeated again

Comment: Yes, all the changes that you have mentioned above. Also this time I am getting images of other ids against single user id. I mean not just 3 images, which I was getting. Here I am getting 6 pictures, whereas in the query I have fixed limit as 3.

Comment: show your entire code. May be issue in other code also

Comment: My Controller and Model are complete codes here, I have edited my view and have added all the codes.